# Retrieving pdf and image files together from storage

Tags: android

Is there any way to retrieve all **.pdf** and **image** files from the storage together as i want to make a custom gallery where i can see both to choose files. Is this possible ?

Comment: ha pdf aney images both.. nai to mane pdf and images differently fetch karine ek list ma mukvi padse.. last option..

Comment: Ha aem j kro Images Cursor thi ane Pdf File ma loop fervi ne fatch kro

Comment: yep ej karvu padse biju koi option nai dekhato.. thx.